# What is the difference between returning a boost::shared_ptr and constructing a boost::shared_ptr from a returned raw pointer?

Tags: c++, boost, shared-ptr

Can someone tell me the difference between these two methods when used as below?

If I use CreateBoostContainer, my code works well. If I use CreateContainer however, I get a boost::bad_weak_ptr exception later in the code in function Foo when trying to use shared_from_this on the ContainerC. I'm using only one thread.

Thanks!

Usage:

```
SceneElementNodeC* poNode(new SceneElementNodeC(CreateBoostContainer()));
SceneElementNodeC* poNode(new SceneElementNodeC(boost::shared_ptr<SceneElementI>(CreateContainer())));
```

Definitions:

```
boost::shared_ptr<SceneElementI> LoaderC::CreateBoostContainer() const
{
    return boost::shared_ptr<SceneElementI>(new ContainerC());
}

SceneElementI* LoaderC::CreateContainer() const
{
    return new ContainerC();
}
```

SceneElementNodeC:

```
class SceneElementNodeC
{
    SceneElementNodeC(boost::shared_ptr<SceneElementI> spSceneElement)
    : m_spSceneElement(spSceneElement)
    {};
}
```

ContainerC:

```
class ContainerC : public SceneElementI, public boost::enable_shared_from_this<ContainerC>
{
    ContainerC()
    {};

    void Foo(VisitorI* poVisitor)
    {
        poVisitor->Visit(shared_from_this());
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, `CreateBoostContainer` is a **terrible** name, the Boost library contains hundreds of components including several containers, `shared_ptr` is just one small part of Boost.  If you later changed the code to return a `std::shared_ptr` instead you'd have to rename the functions, so would you change it to `CreateStdContainer`?!

Secondly you have failed to provide complete code that allows the problem to be reproduced, so according to the rules of Stackoverflow your question should be closed!  I am guessing that your type is defined like this:

```
class ContainerC
: public SceneElementI, public boost::enable_shared_from_this<ContainerC>
{
  // ...
};
```

The difference is that in this function:

```
boost::shared_ptr<SceneElementI> LoaderC::CreateBoostContainer() const
{
    return boost::shared_ptr<SceneElementI>(new ContainerC());
}
```

You initialize the `shared_ptr` with a `ContainerC*` so the `shared_ptr` constructor is able to detect that there is a `enable_shared_from_this` base class (by an implicit upcast to `enable_shared_from_this<ContainerC>`)

Whereas in this function:

```
SceneElementI* LoaderC::CreateContainer() const
{
    return new ContainerC();
}
```

you lose information about the dynamic type of the object by converting the pointer to the base class before creating the `shared_ptr`.  The returned pointer is `SceneElementI*` which (I assume) does not have an `enable_shared_from_this` base class, so when that pointer is later used to initialize a `shared_ptr` it is not possible to tell that it points to a base class of a type that is also derived from `enable_shared_from_this<ContainerC>`.

You could make the first function also fail to work by doing this:

```
boost::shared_ptr<SceneElementI> LoaderC::CreateBoostContainer() const
{
    SceneElementI* ptr = new ContainerC();
    return boost::shared_ptr<SceneElementI>(ptr);
}
```

This is equivalent, because it converts the pointer to `SceneElement*` before creating the `shared_ptr`.

`shared_ptr` is clever and makes use of the pointer type you construct it with even if that is not the type being stored in the `shared_ptr`, so if you upcast that pointer first then `shared_ptr` is not able to be clever.

Comment: First of all thank you for the elaboration on the difference, that was exactly what I didn't understand.

Comment: Regarding the naming of CreateBoostContainer, of course this is terrible, but it was just to distinguish the two functions in this question. About the second point, you're right but I hope that in such a case one still has the chance to improve the question (which I will certainly do) instead of having it closed right away ;)

Answer (score 1):

[Documentation for enable_shared_from_this](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/smart_ptr/enable_shared_from_this.html)

> Requires: enable_shared_from_this must be an accessible base class
> of T. *this must be a subobject of an instance t of type T . There
> must exist at least one shared_ptr instance p that owns t.

Note, "**There must exist at least one shared_ptr instance p that owns t**".

If you use `CreateContainer` then there is no `shared_ptr` instance that owns it.

Comment: The constructed SceneElementNodeC owns a shared_pointer, so there is one, or am I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

[Using the raw pointer at all is poor form.](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm) This is why it's typical to use something like `std::make_shared` - to prevent any possible memory leak. Consider that an exception may be thrown between the point at which you new the class and when it gets associated to a smart pointer.

Having said that, I believe this is just an implementation detail of how boost's [enable_shared_from_this](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/smart_ptr/enable_shared_from_this.html) works.

Comment: Even if it is an implementation detail, what is the difference whether I use the first or the second method? I don't see any difference at the moment where shared_from_this is used, which is when the constructed SceneElementNodeC owns the shared_pointer.